# Get Output of system("insmod mmodule.ko")

Tags: c, system, insmod

I want to run shell command in C program and get stdout output.

I did it in this function:

```
int run_shell_cmd_nout(const char* cmd)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char out[4096]     = {0};
    char str[256]       = {0};
    char full_cmd[1024] = {0};
    int result = 0;

    // Compose full shell command
    if (!sprintf(full_cmd, "/system/bin/%s", cmd))
    {
        printf("Failed to compose full shell command\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Open the command for reading.
    fp = popen(full_cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to run command\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Read the output a line at a time - output it.
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
         if(fgets(str, 256, fp) != NULL)
         {
             result = -1;
             strcat(out, str);
         }
    }

    pclose(fp);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", out);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work with insmod.

Is there any way to intercept all outputs when invoke insmod?

Comment: Yep. Research for `IPC` or `pipe`s or things like this. There are many duplicates here.

Comment: `/system/bin`? really? is that Android or what?

Comment: @meh: wrong, `popen` is perfectly adequate.

Comment: @n.m. - and what does `popen` do? Opens a `pipe`. And what is the `pipe` - an IPC method. Which exactly is the wrong part of my comment?

Comment: @n.m. - Yes, this is for Android

Comment: Does `insmod` even give any output? You specifically mention catching `stdout`, but I expect `insmod` to only write to `stderr`.

Comment: BTW, about `while(!feof(fp))`: see http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html

Comment: And you've got some potential buffer overflows. You're not doing any checking before calling `sprintf` and `strcat`.

Comment: Oh, and you don't say what is meant by "doesn't work".

Comment: No, `popen` runs a program and returns a `FILE*`. That's *what* it does. Pipes are *how* it does what it does, which is totally irrelevant until you master the *what* part.